# "Out Of Range Exception" Error when trying to load DataGridView Row Values into Comboboxes

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm trying to write a program that loads an excel sheet into a Datagridview (successfully), but when I select a Row to try and load them into my Comboboxes I get this Error Message ("System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Arg_ParamName_Name").

If I delete the If Statement the same Error appears on the first "Items.Add" Line of Code.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array indices start at zero in C#.
This means that

```
array[array.Length]
```

is out of range while

```
array[array.Length - 1]
```

is not out of range provided that `0 < array.Length`.